# How to change default Devise "resource" naming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rename, default

By default [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/) refers to a user with variables `resource`, `resource_name`, `resource_class`  and the like in controllers and views.

Is it possible to safely change this default to make Devise to refer to users with a custom name e.g. `user`, `user_name`, `user_class`, etc.? If so, how to make that?

Answer (score 1):

### YAGNI

The only reason why the `resource_name` and `resource_class` methods exist is that Devise does not make any assumptions about the name of the class(es) that its authenticating. The class name is derived from the routes - this is known as the Devise mapping.

If you want to break this abstaction and make your code only work for a single class just reference the class `User` explicitly. Aliasing the methods to `user_name` and `user_class` doesn't do anything except add an additional layer of indirection and a lot of potential confusion/bugs.

If you want to alias `resource` then go right ahead - but its kind of pointless since it's only used in the Devise controllers/views and will require you to re-write the generated code needlessly and makes your code less useful if you ever wanted to extract it out into a library.

Answer (score 0):

There is such file in Devise

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb

You can monkey patch it

```rb
# app/controllers/devise_controller.rb

class DeviseController < ApplicationController
  %w[resource resource_name signed_in_resource resource_class resource_params].each do |method_name|
    new_method_name = method_name.sub(/resource/, 'user')

    alias_method new_method_name, method_name

    helper_method(new_method_name) if respond_to?(:helper_method)
  end
end
```

After that you can use new aliases, for example:

```rb
form_for(user, as: user_name, url: registration_path(user_name)
```

Comment: It would be better to place this monkey patch into a module which you include where needed.

Comment: @mechnicov, after this monkey patch, how should I use the new methods in controllers/views e.g. in view template, should I use `form_for(user, :as => user_name, :url => session_path(user_name)) do |f| ... end`? and, in controller, should I use [`def update_user(user, params) ... end`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)?

Comment: BTW By putting your code in `config/initializers/devise.rb` I get the error "uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)" at line `class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize`.